# New classic analytics account creation

Tags: google-analytics

Whenever creating an analytics account there was a screen prompting for universal or classic analytics choice.  I am unable to see that screen. I want to create a classic analytics account.  How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't - with Universal Analytics out of beta all new properties will be UA. There's no option for Classic GA anymore.